# How to import multiple python modules with same name with C++

Tags: python, c++

I use `PyImport_ImportModule` to import python module in C++.

Now i have two Python module files with same name in different folder like:

```
c:\Demo1\plugin.py and c:\Demo2\plugin.py
```

I know in python, can use

```
import Demo1.plugin as p1
import Demo2.plugin as p2
```

How to do it in C++, with `PyImport_ImportModule` or otherwise?

I find a workaround: execute  `python c:\Demo1\plugin.py` and get the output from it, but it isn't a good solution.

Comment: What do you mean by 'import'? Do you mean `#include`?

Comment: No, i mean c++ use api PyImport_ImportModule to import python module files and call their functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just import a file I would use `PyObject* PyImport_ImportModule(const char *name)`

```
PyObject *p1 = PyImport_ImportModule( "Demo1.plugin" );
PyObject *p2 = PyImport_ImportModule( "Demo2.plugin" );
```

which should work just fine if your path is set correctly. Alternatively you can use `PyObject* PyImport_Import(PyObject *name)`, but then you have to manage the refcounting of the name.

```
PyObject *s1 = PyUnicode_FromString( "Demo1.plugin" );
PyObject *s2 = PyUnicode_FromString( "Demo2.plugin" );

PyObject *p1 = PyImport_Import( s1 );
PyObject *p2 = PyImport_Import( s2 );

Py_DECREF( s1 );
Py_DECREF( s2 );
```

You may need to add an `__init__.py` file to the `Demo1` and `Demo2` folders.

Comment: Thank you , it solves my problem, i use ```PyImport_ImportModule( "Demo1.plugin" );``` before, but my path set error ,so it failed. Now i set right sys.path and the two solutions is all effective to me

Answer (score 0):

You can include them in this manner

```
include "headers/myHeader.h"
include "../moreHeaders/myHeader.h"
```

Just make sure to use different namespaces in both of the header files to access the variables and functions

Comment: Sorry, i changed the question's title, i mean call python module in c++ , please read my question again